# How to group by time-range without taking care of day/month/year in javascript

Tags: javascript, database, group-by, timestamp

##### Hi!

I need to create from a list of inputs with timestamps(**data**) an array of objs showing the scores related to their time range (**result**) without taking care of day/month/year.

I think to do it i need first to create an array of sub arrays of objs organized by time-range then map all (**groupByTimeRange**) and i don't have any clue of how to do it.

Time Range:

- 8h includes 6h to 9h29
- 11h includes 9h30 to 12h29
- 14h includes 12h30 to 15h29
- 17h includes 15h30 to 18h29
- 20h includes 18h30 to 23h59

#### Data

```
 const data = 
   [
    {id: 3337, score: 75, date: '2000-02-02T07:25:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3336, score: 30, date: '2012-06-02T08:24:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3335, score: 25, date: '2020-08-02T09:23:00.000Z'},
    {id: 2234, score: 85, date: '2018-08-02T12:20:00.000Z'},
    {id: 1534, score: 85, date: '2016-08-02T10:30:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3884, score: 85, date: '2019-08-02T11:18:00.000Z'},
    {id: 6534, score: 25, date: '2012-08-02T13:01:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3484, score: 14, date: '2022-08-02T15:22:00.000Z'},
    {id: 2224, score: 87, date: '2021-08-02T14:17:00.000Z'},
    {id: 2234, score: 59, date: '2018-08-02T17:20:00.000Z'},
    {id: 1534, score: 48, date: '2016-08-02T18:24:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3884, score: 25, date: '2019-08-02T16:18:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3287, score: 21, date: '2000-02-02T19:25:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3496, score: 05, date: '2012-06-02T20:24:00.000Z'},
    {id: 9635, score: 67, date: '2020-08-02T22:23:00.000Z'}
   ],
```

#### Grouping by time range 8h/11h/14h/17h/20h

These part i don't know how to do it.

```
const groupByTimeRange = 
 [
   // Group Time range: 8h
   [
    {id: 3337, score: 75, date: '2000-02-02T07:25:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3336, score: 30, date: '2012-06-02T08:24:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3335, score: 25, date: '2020-08-02T09:23:00.000Z'}
   ],
   // Group Time range: 11h 
   [
    {id: 2234, score: 85, date: '2018-08-02T12:20:00.000Z'},
    {id: 1534, score: 85, date: '2016-08-02T10:30:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3884, score: 85, date: '2019-08-02T11:18:00.000Z'}
   ],
   // Group Time range: 14h 
   [
    {id: 6534, score: 25, date: '2012-08-02T13:01:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3484, score: 14, date: '2022-08-02T15:22:00.000Z'},
    {id: 2224, score: 87, date: '2021-08-02T14:17:00.000Z'}
   ],
   // Group Time range: 17h 
   [
    {id: 2234, score: 59, date: '2018-08-02T17:20:00.000Z'},
    {id: 1534, score: 48, date: '2016-08-02T18:24:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3884, score: 25, date: '2019-08-02T16:18:00.000Z'}
   ],
   // Group Time range: 20h 
   [
    {id: 3287, score: 21, date: '2000-02-02T19:25:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3496, score: 05, date: '2012-06-02T20:24:00.000Z'},
    {id: 9635, score: 67, date: '2020-08-02T22:23:00.000Z'}
   ],
  ]
```

#### Expected output

```
const result = 
  [
    {timeRange:"8h", AverageScore: 43%},
    {timeRange:"11h", AverageScore: 85%},
    {timeRange:"14h", AverageScore: 42%},
    {timeRange:"17h", AverageScore: 44%},
    {timeRange:"20h", AverageScore: 31%}
  ]
```

Thanks a lot taking time helping me.

If something is not clear let me know in comments and i will change it

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version

```js
const ranges = [
{ name: "0h", start: "00:00", end: "06:29" },
{ name: "8h", start: "06:00", end: "09:29" },
{ name:"11h", start: "09:30", end: "12:29" },
{ name:"14h", start: "12:30", end: "15:29" },
{ name:"17h", start: "15:30", end: "18:29" },
{ name:"20h", start: "18:30", end: "23:29" }];

const groupByTimeRange = data.reduce((acc,cur) => {
  const time = cur.date.split("T")[1].slice(0,-8); // many ways to skin a cat
  const range = ranges.find(range => time >= range.start && time <= range.end); // find returns the first found
  const name = range.name;
  (acc[name] = acc[name] || []).push(cur); // (if there, reuse, otherwise create) then push
  return acc;
},{})

console.log(groupByTimeRange)

const results = Object.entries(groupByTimeRange).map(([key,val]) => {
  const sum =  val.reduce((a,b) => { return a+b.score },0);
  const avg = Math.round(sum/val.length);
  return  {"timeRange": key, "AverageScore": `${avg}%` };
});

console.log(results);
```

```html
<script>
const data =    [
    {id: 3337, score: 75, date: '2000-02-02T07:25:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3336, score: 30, date: '2012-06-02T08:24:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3335, score: 25, date: '2020-08-02T09:23:00.000Z'},
    {id: 2234, score: 85, date: '2018-08-02T12:20:00.000Z'},
    {id: 1534, score: 85, date: '2016-08-02T10:30:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3884, score: 85, date: '2019-08-02T11:18:00.000Z'},
    {id: 6534, score: 25, date: '2012-08-02T13:01:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3484, score: 14, date: '2022-08-02T15:22:00.000Z'},
    {id: 2224, score: 87, date: '2021-08-02T14:17:00.000Z'},
    {id: 2234, score: 59, date: '2018-08-02T17:20:00.000Z'},
    {id: 1534, score: 48, date: '2016-08-02T18:24:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3884, score: 25, date: '2019-08-02T16:18:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3287, score: 21, date: '2000-02-02T19:25:00.000Z'},
    {id: 3496, score: 05, date: '2012-06-02T20:24:00.000Z'},
    {id: 9635, score: 67, date: '2020-08-02T22:23:00.000Z'}
   ]
</script>
```

Comment: My god i'm learning so much with you guys !! 
Thanks a lot.. 
And interesting way of solving it in an objet with keys !!

Comment: How do we call these kind of problems? these goes into Algorithms or Algorithms patterns? i feel i need to practice more these kind of things!!

Comment: I would say it is a parsing issue

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to store ranges in an array of triples `name - min - max`:

```
const ranges = [
    ['8h', '06:00', '09:29'],
    ['11h', '09:30', '12:29'],
    ['14h', '12:30', '15:29'],
    ['17h', '15:30', '18:29'],
    ['20h', '18:30', '23:59'],
]
```

and iterate over ranges of find out where the date belongs:

```
function getRange(date) {
    let hm = date.slice(11, 16)
    for (let [name, min, max] of ranges) {
        if (min <= hm && hm <= max)
            return name;
    }
}
```

Once this works, loop over the main array and populate the grouping map:

```
let groups = new Map()

for (let d of data) {
    let rng = getRange(d.date)
    if (!groups.has(rng))
        groups.set(rng, [])
    groups.get(rng).push(d)
}
```

The `.values()` of this map will be your `groupByTimeRange` array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply.  i need to study your code to understand it step by step. I'm a junior dev so i'm founding new things of js in your code that i didn't knew about !!

Comment: @Momo: sure, let us know if you have questions.